# How does GHC represent `undefined :: Void` at run-time?

Tags: haskell, null, runtime, ghc

The [`Void`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/void/docs/Data-Void.html#t:Void) type has no values, besides `undefined`. How does GHC represent `undefined :: Void` at runtime?

Answer (score 14):

The same way all unevaluated expressions are represented, namely with a pointer to a thunk.  When the thunk is evaluated it will throw an exception.

Comment: So GHC does not give `Void` any run time representation at all? What if I ask GHC how much space `Void` is supposed to take?

Comment: There can be `t :: Void` but all such `t` terms throw or loop or are unsafely coerced from something else. We don't define a `Void` constructor, so naturally there's no such thing. You can't ask GHC about `Void`'s size as it is, because all unlifted values have the exact same size. What we can do is [inspect](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-datasize-0.1.2/docs/GHC-DataSize.html) runtime closures/objects and compute sizes in various ways. Runtime computed sizes for `t :: Void` would dependent on the specific object behind `t`.

Comment: @PyRulez How do you plan to ask that question?

Comment: Edit: I mean *lifted* values have the same size.

Comment: @PyRulez The representation of `Void` is identical to that of any other lifted type: a pointer to some sort of heap object. The only special thing about `Void` is that that heap object will never turn out to be a data constructor, since `Void` has none.

Comment: It's only semi-special; you can make all sorts of similarly bottom-only types. `data Zero`, `Int :~: Bool`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike C++ and some other modern OO languages, Haskell with GHC does not bring types to runtime, type information was used in type checks during compilation then lost. `Void` doesn't have any constructors or meaningful inhabitants so it simply doesn't exist at runtime.

`undefined` is of bottom type, as bottom is the inhabitant of every data type (or bottom is the subtype of every data type), it will pass the compilation regardless of its expected type, therefore `undefined :: Void` and any other `undefined :: T` are the same thing at runtime namely a pointer to an thunk that raises exception when evaluated.